# What is the settings menu key in No Man's Sky on PC?

Tags: pc, no-mans-sky

How do I bring up the settings menu in No Man's Sky?

I've tried searching the web but have only found documentation of the in-game controls.

Comment: Are you on PC or PS4?

Comment: I'm on a PC Timmy

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> is how you upload discoveries, examine your milestones, change controls, view and change options, and change graphical settings.

Comment: I think `P` is the default as well.